# Upload the image using poup window in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i placed one image control for displaying the image in a page .and i put one link button next to it.when click on that link button i want to open one pop up page in that i want to place one file upload control by using that i want to change my photo.whenever click on upload button in popup page the photo in mainpage should be change and close that poup window.

pls help how to do this .............

Comment: do you want to save the image on server before displaying in mainpage or you just want client side update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to user JavaScript for this. You could try the following:
Suppose you have two pages:
 Page1.aspx
 Page2.aspx

The Image control and the hyperlink are in Page1.aspx.
In Page1.aspx, add the following Javascript code (inside the *script* tag):

```
function RefreshImage()
    {
        document.getElementById["FunnyImage"].attributes.item["src"]="<whateverimage.jpg";
    }
```

Where FunnyImage is the "ID" of the image control.

Im Page2.aspx, add the following Javascript code (inside the *script* tag, of course):

```
private void CloseWindow()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("window.opener.RefreshImage();");
    sb.Append("window.close();");

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", 
        sb.ToString(), true);
}
```

And call the *CloseWindow()* function from wherever you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to save the new image to the same location as before.